# Parchis game: number of pawns won't stop by 4

Tags: java

For a school project we need to make the game 'Parchis', but we are a bit struggling. Normally there is a maximum of 4 pawns in the game for each color. in our case, this number does not want to stop at 4, but sometimes a player can have 6 or 7 pawns. We found out why: if two pawns of the same color land on the same square, the code counts this as 1 pawn while 2 pawns are allowed to land on the same square (according to the assignment). How can I make sure that 2 pawns are allowed on the same square (also with different color) so that the number of pawns per color on the board is 4 at most?

In this photo, you can see our class 'Pawn' where we create a new pawn.

```
public class Pion {
    private Kleur kleur;

    public Pion(Kleur kleur) {
        this.kleur = kleur;
    }


    public Kleur getKleur() {
        return this.kleur;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Pion{" +
                "kleur=" + kleur +
                '}';
    }
}
```

The next class is Parchis, where we have put the course of the game. It is a big method but this way I hope it is clear enough.

```
int beurt = 0;
int vakjesInDoel = 0;
public void speel() {
    label33:
    while (!this.einde()) {
        beurt++;
        vakjesInDoel = 0;
        java.util.Iterator var2 = this.spelers.iterator();

        while (true) {
            while (true) {
                Speler speler;

                if (!var2.hasNext()) {
                    continue label33;
                }

                speler = (Speler) var2.next();
                if (speler.type == Type.NORMAAL) {
                    this.basics.drukEenKnop();
                }
                this.currentSpeler = speler;
                this.basics.spelerBeurt(this.currentSpeler);
                ArrayList<Vakje> lijstSpelerPion = currentSpeler.getVakjesMetPion();
                for (int i = 0; i < lijstSpelerPion.size(); i++) {
                    if (currentSpeler.getVakjesMetPion().get(i).getTypeVakje() == TypeVakje.DOEL) {
                        vakjesInDoel++;
                        //TODO kijken of de juiste methode is aangeroepen
                        if(currentSpeler.iterator.hasNext()){
                            int kies = this.currentSpeler.kies(currentSpeler.kleur, currentSpeler.getPionOpBord());
                            this.bord.movePion((Pion) ((Vakje) lijstSpelerPion.get(kies - 1)).getPionList().get(0), (Vakje) lijstSpelerPion.get(kies - 1), 10);
                        }

                    }
                }
                System.out.println("BeurtNR #" + this.beurt + "  Pionnen in spel " + currentSpeler.getPionOpBord() + "  pionnen in doel: " + this.bord.getLandingsbaan().get(7).getPionList().size());
                new Scanner(System.in);
                this.resultaatDobbel = this.dobbelsteen.gooiDobbelsteen();

                for (int aantal_zes = 0; aantal_zes < 2; aantal_zes++) {
                    if (this.resultaatDobbel == 6) {
                        ArrayList<Vakje> lijstVakjesMetPion = this.iterator.verplaats(this.currentSpeler.getKleur());
                        if (currentSpeler.getPionOpBord() < 4) {
                            if (lijstVakjesMetPion.size() > 0) {
                                this.currentSpeler.locatieSpelerPion();
                                int kies = this.currentSpeler.kies(currentSpeler.kleur, currentSpeler.getPionOpBord());
                                this.bord.movePion((Pion) ((Vakje) lijstVakjesMetPion.get(kies - 1)).getPionList().get(0), (Vakje) lijstVakjesMetPion.get(kies - 1), this.resultaatDobbel);
                                if (speler.type.equals(Type.NORMAAL)) {
                                    this.basics.drukEenKnop();
                                    this.resultaatDobbel = this.dobbelsteen.gooiDobbelsteen();
                                   // this.checkResult();
                                } else {
                                    this.resultaatDobbel = this.dobbelsteen.gooiDobbelsteen();
                                    //this.checkResult();
                                }
                            } else {
                                if (speler.type.equals(Type.NORMAAL)) {
                                    this.basics.drukEenKnop();
                                    this.resultaatDobbel = this.dobbelsteen.gooiDobbelsteen();
                                  //  this.checkResult();
                                } else {
                                    this.resultaatDobbel = this.dobbelsteen.gooiDobbelsteen();
                                   // this.checkResult();
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            this.currentSpeler.locatieSpelerPion();
                            int kies = this.currentSpeler.kies(currentSpeler.kleur, currentSpeler.getPionOpBord());
                            this.bord.movePion((Pion) ((Vakje) lijstVakjesMetPion.get(kies - 1)).getPionList().get(0), (Vakje) lijstVakjesMetPion.get(kies - 1), this.resultaatDobbel + 1);
                        }
                    }

                }

                if (this.resultaatDobbel == 5 && (currentSpeler.getPionOpBord() < 4)) {
                  /*  if (currentSpeler.getPionOpBord() >= 4) {
                        System.out.println("DIT IS NIET OK ALS JE DIT PRINT");
                    }*/
                    this.bord.addPion(this.currentSpeler.getKleur());
                    System.out.println("Nieuwe Pion toegevoegd op bord");
                } else {
                    ArrayList<Vakje> lijstVakjesMetPion = this.iterator.verplaats(this.currentSpeler.getKleur());
                    if (lijstVakjesMetPion.size() > 0) {
                        this.currentSpeler.locatieSpelerPion();
                        int kies = this.currentSpeler.kies(currentSpeler.kleur, currentSpeler.getPionOpBord());
                        this.bord.movePion((Pion) ((Vakje) lijstVakjesMetPion.get(kies - 1)).getPionList().get(0), (Vakje) lijstVakjesMetPion.get(kies - 1), this.resultaatDobbel);
                    }
                }
```

If there is any question or doubts, please hit me up.

We tried for a if structure and a maximum of 4 pawns but it didn't work. We also tried a maximum of numbers in the class 'Pawn' but nothing.

Comment: Your method `speel` is very large, and also contains too many nestings (a for loop within a while loop within a while loop within a while loop). I strongly suggest you split up your method into smaller chunks, so the cognitive complexity is reduced.

Comment: It's hard to follow your code as it's not written in English and thus I'm not sure what is meant to happen where in that snippet. However, you could try the following: 1) maintain a list of pawns owned by the player to enforce a maximum of 4, 2) maintain a relation between a pawn and its location (square) - the pawn would be responsible for updating it so whenever you move a pawn it "unregisters" from the source square and registers on the target square. ...

Comment: 3) for each square maintain a list of pawns (or pieces in general) and before trying a move check for the constraints - since the number of pieces/pawns on a square would expected to be low (at least that's what I'd assume) a list or even array might be efficient enough, i.e. you'd just check all the other pieces already on that square to see if the move would be allowable.

Comment: I didn't read all this code, because as others said, it is way too complex in structure. But playing pieces onto each other is an indicator that you don't check if the grid cell is empty or not.